# Excel 2010 save as web page

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2000/2003 there was an option to save as a Web Page. So long as the workbook had only one sheet, this would create a single HTML file that contained the sheet's data and attributes in a sort of "extended" HTML format as [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155477%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

In Excel 2010, it appears the only option is to create an MHT file which is in a different format altogether.

I have a web based application I'm responsible for which relies on the "old" Office HTML format for certain purposes, so my question is: is there a way in Excel 2010 to export/save as a web page using that old format, or at least as an HTML file of *some* sort?

Comment: This was rather silly for a first question. In  my defense, the list of file types in old versions of Excel was not scrollable, so I wasn't expecting that here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I just fired up Excel 2010, and did a "File -> Save As" and in the "Save as type" drop down I see "web page (*.htm;*.html)" as an option right beneath the "Single File Web Page (*.mht;*.mhtml)" option you mentioned.

Comment: Ok it looks like if you do that and choose the single sheet option, it works. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting web page from the drop down box when clicking save as, saved an HTML file for me.

[image]